# Does props change trigger component rerender?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, render, lifecycle

React docs tells that props or state change triggers component rerender. With state i kinda understand how React knows that something did happened: if we change state directly (by = assignment) it won't trigger rerender because reference to state object doesn't change, that's why we use `useState` - it makes immutable changes under the hood - creates new object with new reference, reference change - react rerender.
But what about props object? How react know when i change one field in props object and it needs to rerender?
PS there is an [Article](https://www.developerway.com/posts/react-re-renders-guide) that says it's a myth, and props change doesn't trigger component rerender, what does it - is changing state inside parent component (part of which we pass as props) - parent component rerender - child component also rerenders.
PSS i tried to pass as a props the variable i initialized outside of component (let's say some global) and i have button to change its value. When i change its value - component doesn't rerender.

Comment: React docs tells that props or state change triggers component rerender. source?

Comment: I believe it's not so much that "the children know their props have changed" more so that when a component re-renders, React runs down the whole component tree from there down, re-rendering all descendants. Then again, Stack Overflow is for questions about debugging specific issues, rather than discussion about the inner workings of popular libraries.

Comment: @TusharShahi [An update can be caused by changes to props or state](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#updating)